# Platform.runLater() doesn't work for not on fx application thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to build "Stick Hero" board game using javafx (JDK8). I use

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    // do some graphical changes
                    playGame();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    });
```

to listen to keyboard and by pressing enter the vertical line turns into a horizontal bridge and the human pass the bridge and this will continue until the length of bridge doesn't match the distance. Now i want to update UI during `playGame()` method is running. When i tried to do `scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(score));` and update the `scoreLabel` text i encountered `Not on FX application thread` error. `playGame()` is something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < cycle; i++) {
        goOneCycle();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fixPosition();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and in `goOneCycle();` and `fixPosition();` i do some graphical changes but it does not shown until the end of the loop.
Now i have two questions. First why i can do stuff like `scoreLabel.setLayoutX(500);` but i cannot do `scoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(score));` i mean in the first case i do not encounter `Not on FX application thread`. And how i can update `scoreLabel` text. Notice that i already tried to use `Platform.runLater()` but when i use this animations and graphical changes will not shown in `playGame()` method, and just the final frame is shown -all of the animations is done but it does not shown.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what threads do and what `Platform.runLater()` does. See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests/30250308#30250308) helps. For "why can I do stuff like `scoreLabel.setLayout(500)` but not `scoreLabel.setText(...)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863205/multi-threading-error-when-binding-a-stringproperty/30868003#30868003

Comment: Don't create a new thread on each key press, and wrap `fixPosition` call in `Platform.runLater`. Also you may consider using animation api...